# Android start application through shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am starting an application through the `Android shell` by using the following string

```
am start -S -W -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER com.package.name
```

However, this line is not starting the application (or any applications). How can I start an application through the `shell` as if it was started by the user; instead of specifying and starting a specific `Activity` with the `shell`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [monkey](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) tool specifying 1 as `event-count`:

```
adb shell monkey -p com.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```